# How to build libgit2 with embedded libssh2 on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, libgit2, libssh2

First we build `libssh2` with the `WinCNG` backend using `msvc`:

```
cmake . -DCRYPTO_BACKEND=WinCNG -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%LIBSSH2%
cmake --build . --target install
```

`libgit2` docs say all we have to do is to set `DEMBED_SSH_PATH`, although it fails to mentation what to set it to. Maybe it's so obvious that it seems irrelevant. However: I'm not a `C` guy and have no clue of the cmake build process. From what I understand the folder where the result of the previous built resides with all it's subfolders such as `include` and `bin` should be the correct path, so using `%LIBSSH2%` should be fine.

When finally trying to build `libgit2` running

```
cmake . -DBUILD_CLAR=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DEMBED_SSH_PATH=%LIBSSH2% -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="%LIBGIT2%"
cmake --build . --target install
```

It'll fail because it's unable to find the links to the header files / binaries. We see things along the line of:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol libssh2_init referenced in function
```

I already tried replacing the paths backslashes `\` with normal slashes `/`, since this seems to be a common issue. I also tried explicitly setting

```
set CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=%LIBSSH2%/include
set CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=%LIBSSH2%/lib
```

both faild with the same result.

Can anyone provide a reproducible way to compile `libgit2` with embedded `libssh2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `EMBED_SSH_PATH` means libssh2 sources will be compiled at the same time as libgit2s. This means you don't actually have to compile libssh2 at all.

I managed to get it to compile successfully by downloading the source for libssh2 and libgit2, then running the following commands:

```
cd libgit2
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DBUILD_CLAR=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DEMBED_SSH_PATH="C:/path-to-ssh/libssh2" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="%LIBGIT2%"
cmake --build . --target install
```

Internally, it looks for all files that match `${EMBED_SSH_PATH}/src/*.c`if `EMBED_SSH_PATH` is set.

As for using `WinCNG` as the backend, using embedded SSH creates this file (`libssh2_config.h`) in the libssh2 directory:

```
#define HAVE_WINCNG
#define LIBSSH2_WINCNG
#include "../win32/libssh2_config.h"
```

I assume that means it is already the default backend for an embedded install.

Comment: That worked! No idea why I haven't tried simply linking the source files. Thanks stranger!